# String Manipulation and splitting string

Tags: c#, string

```
string url = "test:app:https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test
```

I need to split this up to display as follows

```
string first = "app";
string second = "https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test";
```

i have tried the following but falls over on the last colon.

```
        string remove= "";
        remove= url.Replace("test:", "");
        string first= remove.Substring(remove.LastIndexOf(':') + 1);
        string second= remove.Substring(0, remove.IndexOf(':'));
```

Doing this i get

```
first = "app";
second = "Test";
```

When i need

```
first = "app";
second = "https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test";
```

Comment: Is the string always prefixed with `test:app:` *or* always prefixed with `test:`?

Comment: @Igor Hi, it will always start with test, but app will change

Comment: Do you also want the include `:Test` at the end of the URL or should that also be removed? Is it always a combination of 4 strings thate are delaminated by the `:` character?

Comment: @Igor he says in the question what the final form of the data should be

Comment: Hi @Igor, it could be 4 strings however sometimes it could be "test:app:https://test@hotmail.co.uk" and i would need it to be "app" and "https://test@hotmail.co.uk"

Comment: You can look into splitting the string by `:` character and then joining it again. Alternatively you can look at the index of the first occurrence of `:` *starting at* index position 4 which negates `test;` and then splitting the string by that index.

Comment: If I run your code, `first` is `"Test"` and `second` is `"app"`...please post the original code. And what will happen if someone adds a port to the url? You have another `:` in that string and can't parse it anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `LastIndexOf` is just a bit wonky.

```
string url = "test:app:https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test";

string remove = url.Replace("test:", "");

string first = remove.Substring(0, remove.IndexOf(":"));
string second = remove.Substring(remove.IndexOf(first) + first.Length + 1);
```

First grab the `app`, and we can use the location of `app` to derive the rest of the string. Because the last index of `:` would be the one in `:Test`. We don't want the last index of `:`. Instead we just want whatever comes after `app`.

Answer (score 1):

As everything is prefixed with `test:` you can use a starting position after that and then split after the first occurrance of the `:` character.

```
const int IndexOfPrefix = 5; // start position after "test:"
string url = "test:app:https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test";
var indexOfApp = url.IndexOf(':', IndexOfPrefix);
var part1 = url.Substring(IndexOfPrefix, indexOfApp - IndexOfPrefix);
var part2 = url.Substring(indexOfApp + 1);

Console.WriteLine(part1);
Console.WriteLine(part2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Split(Char[], Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_) to get the desired number of elements (3 : the first unwanted part, the *first* expected part and the remaining) along with [`Skip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8) to remove the unwanted one  :

```
string url = "test:app:https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test";

var splitted = url.Split(new [] { ':' }, 3).Skip(1).ToArray();
var first = splitted[0];
var second = splitted[1];

Console.WriteLine(first);
Console.WriteLine(second);
```

This outputs

```
app
https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test
```

---

Another way to do that is using regular expressions :

The pattern `:(?<first>.*?):(?<second>.*)` will :

- `:` search for the characters `:`
- `(?<first>.*?)` creates a group named *first* that will match any number of any character (lazy)
- `:` search for the characters `:`
- `(?<second>.*)` creates a group named *second* that will match any number of any character (greedy)

In example :

```
string url = "test:app:https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test";
var pattern = ":(?<first>.*?):(?<second>.*)";
var regex = new Regex(pattern); // using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Match match = regex.Match(url);
if (match.Success)
{
    var first = match.Groups["first"].Value;
    var second = match.Groups["second"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(first);
    Console.WriteLine(second);
}
```

This outputs

```
app
https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test
```

Comment: The `Skip` looks nice, but creates unnecessary garbage and is slower than just doing this.  `var splitted = url.Split(new[] { ':' }, 3); var first = splitted[1]; var second = splitted[2];`

Comment: In such case (3 items), the performance of `Skip` can be neglected.

Comment: You are creating two arrays instead of one (the `ToArray` call).  If this was on the hot path (ran many times) it's a big difference.  Code is just fine, but I'm simply noting you are indeed sacrificing performance solely for code readability.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public void ManipulateStrings()
{
    string url = "test:app:https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test";
    url = url.Replace("test:", "");
    string first = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf(':'));
    string second = url.Substring(url.IndexOf(':') + 1);

}
```

This basically removed `test:` from your string, then assigns first and second their values without creating `string remove = ""` for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the variable with name "first" to "second" and to change the variable with name "second" to "first"

This is your code:

string url = "test:app:https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test";

```
        string remove = "";
        remove = url.Replace("test:", "");
        string second = remove.Substring(0, remove.IndexOf(':'));
        string first = remove.Substring(remove.IndexOf(":") + 1);
```

and this is the correct code:

string url = "test:app:https://test@hotmail.co.uk:Test";

```
        string remove = "";
        remove = url.Replace("test:", "");
        string first = remove.Substring(0, remove.IndexOf(':'));
        string second = remove.Substring(remove.IndexOf(":") + 1);
```